# Maven and cxf: abstractMethodError (getConduit) with web service

Tags: java, apache, maven, cxf, ejbca

i'm trying to connect to EJBCA server with my client run on jboss. If my client is a standalone java application it runs correctly, but when the client is a Rest web service i have this error:

```
    ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/biz].[resteasy-servlet]] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet resteasy-servlet threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/EndpointInfo;)Lorg/apache/cxf/transport/Conduit;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/EndpointInfo;)Lorg/apache/cxf/transport/Conduit;
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:103) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:896) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy242.certificateRequest(Unknown Source)
    at it.prisma.businesslayer.bizlib.certificationauthority.CaHelper.addCertificate(CaHelper.java:336) [classes:]
    at it.prisma.businesslayer.bizws.certificationauthority.TestRestWS.ReleaseCertificate(TestRestWS.java:54) [classes:]
    at it.prisma.businesslayer.bizws.certificationauthority.TestRestWS$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.ReleaseCertificate(TestRestWS$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:288) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:242) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:229) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    ... 29 more
```

this is part of my pom file of maven with cxf dependency:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssl-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.1-b41</version>
</dependency> -->

<!--Prova-->


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.12</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency> -->
```

Anyone know why i have this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mix of 2.7.12 and 3.0.1 versions of the CXF jars.

Comment: these are the last version of all cxf dependency,no?

Comment: if i add only cxf-api dependency i have bad_certificate error, but it's the same keystore and truststore of standalone java application